# gatsby-source-ghost is failing to create the Ghost schema in Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby, ghost-blog, graphiql, gatsby-plugin

I currently have a Gatsby project based on the [Gatsby-Ghost-Starter](https://github.com/TryGhost/gatsby-starter-ghost) project. The Ghost schema is no longer being generated in Gatsby for some reason, and I can't seem to figure out why. As a result, I get the following error:

> There was an error in your GraphQL query:
>
> Cannot query field "icon" on type "GhostSettings".
>
> If you don't expect "icon" to exist on the type "GhostSettings" it is
> most likely a typo. However, if you expect "icon" to exist there are a
> couple of solutions to common problems:
>
> - If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your
>   development server
> - The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields
>   you can query and what shape they have
> - You want to optionally use your field "icon" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the
>   GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that
>   field ("dummy content")
>
> It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want
> to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned
> "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema
> for "GhostSettings":
> https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions

This error message is basically repeated for every page and query field that uses anything related to the Ghost schema. I pulled up the GraphiQL explorer to see if I could access the fields there, and it indicated there is no schema available (as seen in the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4FoP.png)). I tried rolling back to previous commits, deleting .cache and node_modules, updating all packages, and re-cloning the repo to no avail.

My latest commit was able to compile with no problem in the production environment, so I think it's some sort of misconfiguration on my machine...The environment variables are all identical, and I tried using the production Ghost server as my "ghost-source" on my local machine (since I know it works if the production build compiled successfully), but nothing changed. I've been stuck on this for days and have no idea how to even debug what's happening right now. Any advice/insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update: I was able to resolve this issue by downgrading gatsby@2.22.1

Comment: you should answer your own questions